# What php frameworks have database migration support?

Tags: php, frameworks, database-migration

I'm looking for a good php framework with support for handling database migrations. Ideally I would like to be able to run a command that generates a migration script, one that updates the database with changes and can handle rolling back those changes. Is there anything out there that does this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Doctrine project supports migrations - http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/migrations/2.0/docs/reference/introduction/en

*Hmm, that documentation is a bit lacking, at least in the introduction. Hopefully it gets better as it goes on.*

Whilst most popular in Symfony, this can easily be integrated into other frameworks or even used on its own.

Comment: That looks handy. It looks like they're using it in Symfony 2 http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/cookbook/doctrine/migrations.html. I'm guessing that most of what I'm seeing on that page is doctrine wrapped in a little bit of symfony?

Comment: @mozillalives You would be correct. Symfony 2 doesn't try to be everything. Instead, it makes it easy to use other code libraries.

Answer (score 1):

Promising, but not yet have a stable version : https://github.com/fuel/fuel

Comment: I am looking for something a little more mature, but this looks interesting so I'll definitely keep my eye on it. And now I've got that Metallica song stuck in my head ...

Answer (score 1):

There is a new php framework called Laravel and it has migrations the same way as ruby on rails. It seems so pretty!

You can find it at http://laravel.com/

[Migrations Docs](http://laravel.com/docs/database/migrations)

In addition, the framework introduces the idea of bundles, what can give to your project a great modular view.

If you try it, tell us your experience! :)

Comment: Laravel is a fine framework, however if links break or change this answers is not very helpful in the future. Please expand it to at least summarize the basics of migrations, or it will likely continue to be flagged and be automatically removed.

Answer (score 0):

symfony - http://www.symfony-project.org/
In symfony you can write database schema using ORM like Propel, it is independant from database driver. If you have a database already, you want to migrate to a different db, I think you can dump the db, change the db config, and re-import it to the new db. (though I have not tried it myself.)

Comment: Migration in this sense refers to versioning the schema and managing changes, not switching engines

Answer (score 0):

There are much php framework over there that can use any database. For example Zend, Ci, Cake and many others. One thing you should do is change database type that's usually stored in configuration file. And then migrate your database manually. No framework that can generate migration script automatically. U can also use ESF for database migration

Comment: Well at the very least, it looks like Symfony 2 with Doctrine can generate migrations. I do plenty of migrations manually, I would really like a tool to prepare them for me. What's ESF?